# increase Stroke opacity of Zero line in AmCharts

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

[image]

As we can see I have one Bar chart with Positive and Negative bars. In the Middle on the 0th scale, there is one line that you can hardly see. I want to increase its opacity. So, I want to increase the opacity of XAxis or increase the opacity of the Zero line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the [Document](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/axes/#Zero_line) for zero line, but I didn't find any specific solution. Trying by myself I found the way to correctly do it.

and by the following code, we can increase the Zero line's opacity.

```
valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.strokeOpacity = 1;
```

This is the JS version for JSON we can do the following

```
{
  "yAxes": [{
    "type": "ValueAxis",
    "renderer": {
      "baseGrid": {
        "strokeopacity": 1
      }
    }
  }]
}
```